# Compare the different scale in single dataframe column with a single boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I want to compare different scale values within a single column with a boxplot, what could I do? I only know how to use conditions to select the subset. I don't know how to apply it with seaborn.

```
a1 = df[(df['A'] < 10) & (df['A'] > 0)] 
a1 = a1['A']

a2 = df[(df['A'] < 20) & (df['A'] > 10)]
a2 = a2['A']

a3 = df[(df['A'] < 30) & (df['A'] > 20)]
a3 = a3['A']

altitude = pd.DataFrame({"0 < A < 10": a1, "10 < A < 20": a2, "20 < A < 30": a3})
altitude.boxplot()
plt.ylabel("height(m)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `seaborn` you can try :

```
import seaborn as sns

df['class'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[0,10,20,30])
sns.boxplot(y='A', x='class', data=df)
```

With sample data

```
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: nice one:) @Quang Hoang

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful. But I got another problem. I found many of my data become NaN after cut. I use fillna() to fill it but it shows that the datatype is a category. What can I do? : (